# Overwriting user web browser's cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Is overwriting visitor cookies possible ?

Here is the scenario, user visited website A and website A dropped cookies on user's web browser after that user went to my website - am I able to overwrite user's cookies of other website by user visiting my website ?

To simplify it is to change user cookies of an affiliate link abc.com/aaa to abc.com/bbb just by them visiting my site.

Differences between the marked duplicate question: I am talking about editing existing cookies not URL redirection

Comment: Re: your edit. Read a little deeper than the immediate question. It is not possible to change cookies set on another domain. For example, if the user picks up a cookie at `facebook.com`, you will not be able to change it when they visit your site at `mysite.com`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.